# discord music bot with distube | discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots, distube

I have a problem with my code, i try to code a discord music bot  but i always shows a error message in visual studio code. I tried multiple things but none of them worked. I use distube for the bot because its way more easier.

**My code:**

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')
    DisTube = require('distube')
    module.exports = {
        execute: async (client, message, args) => { 

    const distube = new DisTube(client, { searchSongs: false, emitNewSongOnly: false });


client.on("message", async (message) => {
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    if (!message.content.startsWith(config.prefix)) return;
    const args = message.content.slice(config.prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
    const command = args.shift();

    if (command == "play")
        distube.play(message, args.join(" "));
    
    if (command == "stop") {
        distube.stop(message);
        message.channel.send(`**<:miraimusic:828978156512739378> ⁓ Stopped the music!** 
> If you want me to rejoin, type m!play.`);
    }
    if (command == "queue") {
        let queue = distube.getQueue(message);
        message.channel.send(`**<:miraimusic:828978156512739378> ⁓ Current queue**:
> ` + queue.songs.map((song, id) => `**${id + 1}**. ${song.name} - \`${song.formattedDuration}\``
        ).slice(0, 10).join("\n"));
    }

    if ([`3d`, `bassboost`, `echo`, `karaoke`, `nightcore`, `vaporwave`].includes(command)) {
        let filter = distube.setFilter(message, command);
        message.channel.send(`**<:miraimusic:828978156512739378> ⁓ Added filter: **
> ` + (filter || "off"));
    }
    }
);

// DisTube event listeners, more in the documentation page
distube
    .on("playSong", (message, queue, song) => message.channel.send(
        `**<:miraimusic:828978156512739378> ⁓ Playing now:**
> ${song.name}\` - \`${song.formattedDuration}\``
    ))
    .on("addSong", (message, queue, song) => message.channel.send(
        `**<:miraimusic:828978156512739378> ⁓ Added: **
> ${song.name} - \`${song.formattedDuration}\` **to the queue.**`
    ))
    .on("playList", (message, queue, playlist, song) => message.channel.send(
        `**<:miraimusic:828978156512739378> ⁓ Playing now:**
>` `${song.name}\` - \`${song.formattedDuration}\``
    ))
    .on("addList", (message, queue, playlist) => message.channel.send(
        `**<:miraimusic:828978156512739378> ⁓ Added: **
> ${song.name} - \`${song.formattedDuration}\` **to the queue.**`
    ))
    // DisTubeOptions.searchSongs = true
    .on("searchResult", (message, result) => {
        let i = 0;
        message.channel.send(`**Choose an option from below**\n${result.map(song => `**${++i}**. ${song.name} - \`${song.formattedDuration}\``).join("\n")}\n*Enter anything else or wait 60 seconds to cancel*`);
    })
    // DisTubeOptions.searchSongs = true
    .on("searchCancel", (message) => message.channel.send(`Searching canceled`))
    .on("error", (message, e) => {
        console.error(e)
        message.channel.send("An error encountered: " + e);
  }
```

**Error:**

```
music.js(64, 34): The parser expected to find a '}' to match the '{' token here. music.js(5, 51): The parser expected to find a '}' to match the '{' token here. music.js(4, 22): The parser expected to find a '}' to match the '{' token here
```

I don't know what the problem is so yeah, please help me!

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: music.js(64, 34): The parser expected to find a '}' to match the '{' token here.
music.js(5, 51): The parser expected to find a '}' to match the '{' token here.
music.js(4, 22): The parser expected to find a '}' to match the '{' token here.

I'm new to coding, i tried different things but non of them worked.

Comment: Could you add the error message into the question? It's easier for us to read it that way.

Comment: @ツtanni it looks like you're missing a closing "}" somewhere around those lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a few issues with closing ")" and "}". Try to keep your code properly formatted and with good identation so that finding these issues was easier.

Here's the correct code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')
DisTube = require('distube')
module.exports = {
  execute: async (client, message, args) => {

    const distube = new DisTube(client, { searchSongs: false, emitNewSongOnly: false });

    client.on("message", async (message) => {
      if (message.author.bot) return;
      if (!message.content.startsWith(config.prefix)) return;
      const args = message.content.slice(config.prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
      const command = args.shift();

      if (command == "play")
        distube.play(message, args.join(" "));
      
      if (command == "stop") {
        distube.stop(message);
        message.channel.send(`**<:miraimusic:828978156512739378> ⁓ Stopped the music!** 
        > If you want me to rejoin, type m!play.`);
      }
      if (command == "queue") {
        let queue = distube.getQueue(message);
        message.channel.send(`**<:miraimusic:828978156512739378> ⁓ Current queue**:
        > ` + queue.songs.map((song, id) => `**${id + 1}**. ${song.name} - \`${song.formattedDuration}\``
        ).slice(0, 10).join("\n"));
      }

      if ([`3d`, `bassboost`, `echo`, `karaoke`, `nightcore`, `vaporwave`].includes(command)) {
        let filter = distube.setFilter(message, command);
        message.channel.send(`**<:miraimusic:828978156512739378> ⁓ Added filter: **
        > ` + (filter || "off"));
      }
    });

    // DisTube event listeners, more in the documentation page
    distube
      .on("playSong", (message, queue, song) => message.channel.send(`**<:miraimusic:828978156512739378> ⁓ Playing now:**> ${song.name}\` - \`${song.formattedDuration}\``))
      .on("addSong", (message, queue, song) => message.channel.send(`**<:miraimusic:828978156512739378> ⁓ Added: **> ${song.name} - \`${song.formattedDuration}\` **to the queue.**`))
      .on("playList", (message, queue, playlist, song) => message.channel.send(`**<:miraimusic:828978156512739378> ⁓ Playing now:**>` `${song.name}\` - \`${song.formattedDuration}\``))
      .on("addList", (message, queue, playlist) => message.channel.send(`**<:miraimusic:828978156512739378> ⁓ Added: **> ${song.name} - \`${song.formattedDuration}\` **to the queue.**`))
      // DisTubeOptions.searchSongs = true
      .on("searchResult", (message, result) => {
        let i = 0;
        message.channel.send(`**Choose an option from below**\n${result.map(song => `**${++i}**. ${song.name} - \`${song.formattedDuration}\``).join("\n")}\n*Enter anything else or wait 60 seconds to cancel*`);
      })
      // DisTubeOptions.searchSongs = true
      .on("searchCancel", (message) => message.channel.send(`Searching canceled`))
      .on("error", (message, e) => {
        console.error(e)
        message.channel.send("An error encountered: " + e);
      })
  }
}
```

Comment: The code works now, but nothing happens when i use the command. Can you maybe dm me on discord? My tag is: callmeakihito#1337

Comment: @ツtanni Well it's a whole different question. You probably should learn more about Javascript in general before proceeding, taking it step by step, because going straight like this will most likely raise more issues in future.